# Bundle is waiting for namespace handlers

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to deploy my application in fuse container but I get an error - Bundle is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint, http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0, http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jasypt/v1.0.0.

When I try to create the bundle this error occurs for test cases. My blueprint file already have -

```
 <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" 
 xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" 
 xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd            
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel- 
  blueprint.xsd">
```

namespaces. Please let me what exactly is this error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing the schema Location for cm?

```
http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd
```